# Bash "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" during recursion

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

I am trying to code a bash script to generate all combinations of characters but I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". The code uses recursion and from my research of the error I beleave that to be what is causing the issue. Help would be appreciated.

```
letters=$(echo {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9})
letters+=" ' ! @ # $ % ^ & ( ) _ + - = [ ] { } : ; | \ / ? . > , <"
printAllCombos(){
    local prefix=$1
    levelsLeft=$2
    local letters=$3
    if [ $levelsLeft = 0 ]
    then
        echo $prefix
    else
        for i in $letters
        do
            newPrefix=$(echo $prefix$i)
            printAllCombos newPrefix $levelsLeft-1 $letters
        done
    fi
}

printAllCombosTo(){
    levels=$1
    local letters=$2
    for ii in {1..$levels}
    do
        printAllCombos "" ii $letters
    done
}
printAllCombosTo 2 $letters
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `for ii in {1..$levels}` doesn't do what you think it does. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D

Comment: Also, quoting matters. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Beyond that -- it would make more sense to store the list of characters in an array rather than using a string.

Comment: do you know what segfaulted?  Have you tried running the script with `set -x` at the top for debugging output?

Comment: Please show your expected output for a couple of different inputs.

Comment: `$levelsLeft-1` is not the same as `$(( levelsLeft - 1 ))`. The former concatenates `-1` to the string. The latter creates a number with a value 1 smaller than the old value. Right now, where you ought to have a boundary condition, you're just making an infinitely-long string by continually appending `-1`s to the end. Eventually there won't be enough memory on the stack for a new frame with a slightly longer version of the string than the last frame had, allocation will fail, and if that failure isn't handled right you get a segfault. `set -x` shows this happening.

Comment: So actually there are a few variables that just get longer and longer. I am going to re-post after some work.